# Develop a txt2img API for custom frontend

Tags: python, stable-diffusion, gradio

I have been using [Auto1111's webui](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/tree/master) for getting started with diffusion models and LoRas. I want to create my own text-to-image website where users can play around with different models and LoRas that I upload on the server, like a playground of sort.

Hence, I plan on building my own custom frontend ccomponents in React for the same instead of using [gradio](https://www.gradio.app/) elements(since it does not give much UI customisation control), which is the case for Auto1111's repo. I have been trying to disintegrate the backend for the txt2img generation and it is very tricky sincy all the files are contained inside a single modules directory which contains the backend and frontend logic.

I tried understanding the entire pipeline of Auto1111's application and figured that the main files I require for the txt2img generation are:

1. modelloader.py -> Basically takes the .ckpt and .safetensor files from the models>StableDiffusion directory and loads inside the gradio list component
2. processing.py
3. txt2img.py
4. sd_models
   and a few more.....

Is there a simpler and less complex way to create an API for the difffusion models? Otherwise what approach should I use for making my custom frontend with Auto1111's complete backend logic for the text-to-image generation models.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is a broad topic, my answer is not exhaustive but I can help with the direction:
- Automatic 1111 WebUI has an API, you need to start WebUI with the `--api` option, for example like this on Mac: `./webui.sh --api`
- The API documentation has a link on your WebUI running locally, look in the footer of your own WebUI instance in your browser or just go to http://127.0.0.1:7860/docs
- The online documentation is fragmented, you may want to start here https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/discussions/3734